# Make pinescript graphics stay in the Tradingview chart and not go outside of it

Tags: python, pine-script

I am drawing this using pinescript and sometimes it goes out of the chart like so:

[image]

How do I fix this programmatically using pinescript or python?

How do I make sure that the drawing stays inside the chart or move the chart around to get the drawing to become fully visible?